# If a function $g(x)$ is continuous, what happens to $\int_{a}^{x}g(t) dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

$f(x)$, $g(x)$ is a continuous function, and let $$\int_{a}^{x}g(t) dt = \begin{cases} 2x^2-1 & (x\le a) \\ f(x) & (x > a)\end{cases}$$.

At first, I thought $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}g(t) dt = g(x)$$, and since $g$ is a continuous function, it makes its derivatives always exist.
So $\int_{a}^{x}g(t) dt$ becomes a differentiable, and thus a continuous function.

But then I realized this is a circular reasoning because I just did a differentiation to show it is a differentiable function.

How do I know if it's differentiable with correct logic?

Comment: The function indicated in the title is different from the one you are asking.

Comment: Moreover, is your goal trying to determine whether the function $ G(x) := \int_a^x g(t) dt $ is differentiable or not?

Comment: @KenHung I fixed the title. And yes, I want know if it's differentiable or not.

Comment: What is the domain of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @KenHung domain of both function is $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and in particular any closed interval $[c,d] \subset \mathbb{R}$, [the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) guarantees that the function $ G(x) := \int_a^x g(t) dt $ is differentiable at any real number $r$.
It doesn't matter what the definition of $G(x)$ is.

Comment: Oh it was just written in the definition...so, is the integration cannot be defined if the function inside is not continuous?

Comment: That would worth another question, you should post elsewhere.